# Plotting event based errors using matplotli, pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Having a problem where I need to plot when signals indicate error in a horizontal graph (sliding window over time) similar to this broken horizontal bar chart from matplotlib
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-broken-barh-py
[image]

On the x axis i have datetime and y axis the events
My date consist of a few thousand events with the following data in panda dataframes

```
timestamp, signal, value, prev_timestamp
2021-04-21 16:58:37.572495872, MySignal, error, 2021-04-21 16:57:59.576365824
2021-04-21 16:59:05.576416000, MySignal, ok, 2021-04-21 16:57:59.576365824
2021-04-21 17:38:19.616417024, Other, warning 2021-04-21 16:57:59.576365824
```

timestamp is when the event occured with that value and prev_timestamp refers to previous event for this signal. eg diff = prev_timestamp - timestamp
The value could reflect the color of the bars like this `colors = {'error': 'red', 'warning': 'yellow'}`

Have no idea how to filter this and get it to print out correctly with matplotlib.
guess the y axis could be all the signals that have at least once been 'error' or 'warning'

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: Why do you have the `tkinter` tag?

Comment: sorry, my tkinter app that will show this plot, so that tag was a bit out of scope